# Determine start/end times for spans

Tags: sql, sql-server

Summary:
I have a table which contains the following fields from a Sales Order status tracking application
OpportunityID, SalesOrderID, CurrentStatus, PriorStatus, RevisionDateTime

I have built a view against that table which contains the following (using a Lead function):
OpportunityID,SalesOrderID,PriorStatus,CurrentStatus,startTime,endTime,duration (working minutes).

Background:

- There's a 1:Many relationship between Opportunity and SalesOrderID
- Each SalesOrder progresses through the workflow independent of other related SalesOrders
- When the Opportunity is cancelled, all underlying SalesOrders are also cancelled.
- At any time, a SalesOrder may be walked back to a prior status in the workflow

Need:
I need to report on the total period any SalesOrder is in any status.

Sample of data

```
soID | opportunityID | lastStatus | statusName | startTime        | endTime
-----+---------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------------
1    | Q1234         | Open       | Approved   | 11/17/20 10:00AM | 11/17/20 02:00PM
2    | Q1234         | Open       | Approved   | 11/17/20 10:00AM | 11/17/20 02:00PM
3    | Q1234         | Open       | Approved   | 11/17/20 10:00AM | 11/18/20 10:00AM
1    | Q1234         | Hold       | Approved   | 11/20/20 12:00PM | 11/21/20 08:00AM
2    | Q1234         | Confirmed  | Approved   | 11/21/20 12:00PM | 11/22/20 02:00PM
```

Given the above example, I need 2 rows in the result, with Start / End times as follows:

```
1: 11/17/2020 10:00 AM / 11/18/2020 10:00 AM
2: 11/20/2020 12:00 PM / 11/22/2020 12:00 PM
```

I'm almost certain I'll have to use a Stored Procedure to generate the needed results, but I'm stuck. Any pointers?

Revision for clarity:

- The only "Status" field that is relevant is "StatusName", ignore the "lastStatus" column.
- Desired output would include the OpportunityID and the start and end times.
- Logic:
- SOID 1-3 all start at the same time for the initial instance, but end at different times. The min start for that instance would be the reported Start (e.g. 11/17 @ 10 AM), and the max end time for that instance would be the reported End (11/18 @ 10 AM).
- The second output record follows the same logic.

I saw a post that referred to db<>fiddle and WOW - this will hopefully make this easier.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a5674f4a7125f53c0436f9daa0807226

Comment: Morgan, could you please clarify, what exactly you want to report? Your description says "...report on total period any SalesOrder is in any status...". Your example shows 3 statuses (Open, Hold, Confirmed), 3 sales orders (1, 2, 3), while output has only two rows. How did you get these rows, what is logic being "Start" and "End" and how are the values 1 and 2 derived?

Comment: Are you looking to group by opportunityID or sales order?  Not knowing your data, I would assume the first 3 records would be one Opportunity and the last two another opportunity?

Comment: Correct, group by opportunityID, but all 5 records are for the same opportunity - which makes this complicated.

Comment: Is there a higher level sales order table that soID comes from?

Comment: TLDR version: Affirmative. The table which feeds the view is static and flat.

Long version: We have a Sales Order table which doesn't have automatic version/audit history. We're implementing an SQL trigger to create an audit history so we can track where things are getting hung up in the process. The trigger caches the old and new Status values to a custom/flat table, in addition to a timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you learn -

this happens to be the "Gaps and Island" problem. Here's some references for others that stumble upon my poorly worded title.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56593/getting-each-status-change-in-a-table

https://bertwagner.com/posts/gaps-and-islands/

Comment: be a little bit more specific how you solved your own issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27665997)

Comment: Thanks - I was fighting getting the SQL script to store with formatting in the answer and gave up. See what I was doing wrong and it's addressed, now. Thanks all.